# jQuery Cycle IE7+8 Issue - White marks appearing over JPEG

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, jquery-cycle

I am having a spot of bother with the jQuery cycle plugin. Now - all works fine functionality wise, but when it faded to the second slide some little 'white marks' appear on top of my JPEG?

At first I thought this was a z-index issue, but clearly not. I have been doing some research into this and clearly I am unsuccessful otherwise I would not be posting on here! I found that using the options:

```
> cleartype: false, 
> cleartypenoBg: false
```

Could possibly fix this by altering the background color etc; this does not change a thing. I have provided a screenshot of the issue here:

http://www.bccfiles.com/wellieboots-new-2010/images/ieissue.jpg

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is a IE specific hex-color problem. Change the lightness and saturation of the image just a little bit and it will be fixed.